# Describing Moment in a Sentence

Tags: grammar, sentence

Is this sentence correct?

> I want to execute the/a part of my code for once, and exactly the
>   moment  when the key is pressed and a clicked is occurred.

Also, what kind of grammatical structure is used above?

Comment: This belongs on https://ell.stackexchange.com/

Comment: There is quite a lot wrong with the sentence.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to want to say:

> I want to execute a part of my code once, and at exactly the moment
>   when the key is pressed.

Comment: You missed the part of clicking.